# Too many open files issue in siddhi wso2 sp

Tags: apache-kafka, wso2, complex-event-processing, siddhi, wso2-streaming-integrator

while testing the performance of wso2 stream processor server , I have put more that hundred .siddhi files in the deployment directory. which results in "To many open files" issue.

nitty-gritty  of rule that i have is :

1. all the rules listen to same kafka topic
2. each rule has its own group id (so that all of them process the stream simultaniously)
3. when number of .siddhi files in deployment folder exceeds approximately 100 . no other .siddhi files are deployed and siddhi becomes unresponsive.

Can any one let me know :

1.where exaclty i am going wrong?

2. whats the limit of rules to be created on a single siddhi server?

Answer (score 0):

This might be due to your OS configuration. Run the following command to display all current limits.

```
 ulimit -a
```

`ulimit -n 70000` will set the file descriptor limit.

Try out the scenario after increasing the limit.

Also, verify whether you are duplicating the same rule in 100 files or
is it 100 different rules.

Answer (score 0):

What seems to happen here is that you are running out of open file descriptors. As @pcnfernando suggested in the previous answer, you can set the descriptor limit by using `ulimit -n ####`.

However, The real question is why this is happening? This can be due to several reasons. The number of siddhi files that you, and the number of Kafka topics/partitions (since this can also cause too many open connections).

So even you get the issue fixed with `ulimit -n ####`, it's better to do some investigation using `lsof` [1] and see which process is actually causing the issue. This will help you with Q1.

And for the Q2. There's no hard and fast rule of defining the number of Siddhi rules that can be deployed in a single server. It all depends on variables like processing power, memory, and of course the number open file descriptors in this situation.

[1] https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-lsof.html